# How can I find out the index of an item after an aggregation sort?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I would like to be able to display an index of an item in its output.

Here is my code right now:

```
Picks.aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": { 
            _id: "$user.uid", 
            name: { 
                $first: "$user.name" 
            }, 
            total: { 
               $sum: "$total" 
            },
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        "$sort": { 
            "total": -1 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        "$limit": 10 
    }
])
```

I have no problem with using aggregate and I am able to group the needed fields. Here is an example output and I have commented out what I am looking for.

```
[
    {
        _id: "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i",
        name: "Jane Doe",
        total: 7384,
        // next line is what I'm looking for
        // rank: 0 <-- it's the first item in an array after $sort
    },
    {
        _id: "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9",
        name: "John Doe",
        total: 7370,
        // next line is what I'm looking for
        // rank: 1 <-- it's the second item in an array after $sort
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the index directly in the data? For any array, items have indexes implicitly, and chances are if you're accessing an item you have simultaneous access to its index. (e.g. `aggregatedData.map((item, index) => { ... })` - `index` will be available)

Comment: You can use aggregate to add fields to each result item. a common use case is adding a `distance` field to the result items for a geospatial query. you can also simply take your results and `results = results.map((item,index)=>{ item.rank=index; return item;});` doing it in the aggregate is optimal, but you probably don't lose much performance in doing it later with map.